# How do I hide a DIV when I switch to mobile dimensions?

Tags: html, css, amp-html

So, I have written a page in AMP HTML, and I have a DIV I want to hide when someone views the page on mobile, but I want it shown when it's on a resolution such as Desktop or Tablet. I have Bootstrap enabled and all of the CSS is styled in the  of the document, per AMP Standards.

```
<section class="about" id="about" alt="about">

<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Example Content</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<amp-img src="example.jpg" alt="Example" height="400" width="800"></amp-img>
</div>

</section>
```

I want the second DIV in the Section to be hidden on Mobile.

Comment: You use bootstrap ? try hidden-md-down

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Bootstrap 3 is mobile-first. There is no "down".

Comment: Did you try to use media queries or built-in bootstrap classes?

Comment: @isherwood : so just use hidden-*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap has classes for this sort of thing. Use them individually or in combination to achieve the desired result.

`hidden-xs`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Comment: Shouldn't you be using hidden and not visible and targeting small and not extra small?

Comment: `small` stands for portrait tables, `extra-small` for mobile devices. Tracks smaller then 767px. The attached link explains it pretty well.

Comment: It's not that clear-cut. Many phones have the same (or higher) resolution than tablets (which are also "mobile").

Comment: Not really. Even though they have pixel resolutions, they use mostly standart viewports when it comes to the browser.

Example: Nexus 5 (1920x1080) - Browser viewport: 640x360 (@3x)

Answer (score 1):

With CSS3 media queries you can make CSS act different in different resolutions.

Example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #yourdiv {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Here is complete tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just add .hidden-xs class to the element you want to hide from mobile device.

```
<section class="about" id="about" alt="about">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Example Content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 .hidden-xs">
    <amp-img src="example.jpg" alt="Example" height="400" width="800"></amp-img>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Also got the same result with <div class="hidden-xs" align="right">